# std::any_cast throws a bad any_cast error when converting void* to function pointer

Tags: c++, dlopen, any

I wrote the code below,

```
std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::any> symbols_;
symbols_["foo"] = dlsym(handle_), "foo");
```

When i use any_cast
`return (std::any_cast<void(*)()>(symbols_["foo"]))();`, the program will throw a error: bad any_cast.

I found the main reason because of the function .

```
template<typename _Tp>
void* __any_caster(const any* __any)
```

It would judge the condition as false and then return nullptr.

```
else if (__any->_M_manager == &any::_Manager<_Up>::_S_manage
#if __cpp_rtti
      || __any->type() == typeid(_Tp)
#endif
      ){
      any::_Arg __arg;
      __any->_M_manager(any::_Op_access, __any, &__arg);
      return __arg._M_obj;
}
return nullptr;
```

I want to know

1.why `__any->_M_manager == &any::_Manager<_Up>::_S_manage` and `__any->type() == typeid(_Tp)` were all false,

2.and how can i fix the problem(continue to use std::any).

Here is a simple demo.

```
#include <any>

void func() { }

auto main() -> int {
    std::any a = (void*)func;
    std::any_cast<void(*)()>(a)();
    return 1;
}
```

gcc version 10.1.0 (GCC)

Comment: Because the type of `dlsym(handle_, "foo")` is not `void(*)()` but `void*`.

Comment: You stored `void*`, it is beyond reasonable that it will throw if you try to obtain a different type like `char*` or `(void*)()`. Seriously, why do you even ask?

Comment: May I suggest just making the map of type:  `unordered_map<string, void*>`.  You'll have to use reinterpret_cast to the void* value to the function you expect anyway.

Comment: @selbie well, with `std::any` he can store the correct signature from the beginning and then ensure that on each use the same signature is used. Not something `void*` can do.

Comment: `symbols_["foo"] = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(handle_, "foo"));` would seem more appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you store a `void*` in the `std::any` object:

```
symbols_["foo"] = dlsym(handle_, "foo");
```

To instead store a `void(*)()`, you need to cast the `void*` that's returned by `dlsym`:

```
symbols_["foo"] = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(handle_, "foo"));
```

---

In this case, you may want to just store the `void*` and cast when using it instead:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string_view, void*> symbols_;
symbols_["foo"] = dlsym(handle_, "foo");
//...
return reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(symbols_["foo"])();
```

---

A third option, if you don't need the runtime lookup in the `unordered_map`, is to instead store the function pointers in named variables. That makes the usage a little easier. Here's an example:

A generic `class` for loading/unloading a shared library:

```
class Lib { 
public:
    explicit Lib(const char* filename, int flags = RTLD_LAZY) :
        lib(dlopen(filename, flags)) 
    {
        if(!lib) throw std::runtime_error(dlerror());
    }

    Lib(const Lib&) = delete;
    Lib(Lib&& rhs) = delete;
    Lib& operator=(const Lib&) = delete;
    Lib& operator=(Lib&& rhs) = delete;
    virtual ~Lib() { dlclose(lib); }

private:
    struct cast_proxy { // a class to cast to the proper pointer
        // cast to whatever that is needed:
        template<class Func>
        operator Func () { return reinterpret_cast<Func>(sym); }
        void* sym;
    };

protected:
    cast_proxy sym(const char* symbol) const {
        void* rv = dlsym(lib, symbol);
        if(rv) return {rv};                   // put it in the cast_proxy
        throw std::runtime_error(dlerror());
    }

private:
    void* lib;
};
```

A class for loading a specific shared library:

```
class YourLib : public Lib {
public:
    YourLib() : Lib("./libyour_library.so"),
        // load all symbols here:
        foo(sym("foo"))   // the cast proxy will return the correct pointer type
    {}

    // Definitions of all the symbols you want to load:
    void(*const foo)();
};
```

Then using it will be as simple as this:

```
int main() {
    YourLib ml;
    ml.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::any_cast` will only cast back to the type that was stored in the `std::any`. As `dlsym` returns `void*`, that is what is stored in the `std::any`.

You need a separate cast to `void(*)()` either before storing in `std::any` or after the `std::any_cast`:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string_view, std::any> symbols_;
symbols_["foo"] = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(handle_), "foo"));
return (std::any_cast<void(*)()>(symbols_["foo"]))();
```